# getStringArrayListExtra give me a null value but I have values on it

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have a getExtra that have values, but when I try to put it on one ArrayList I recieve a null value and I don't know why. I put the code below and I explain it.

On the mainActivity, on the onCreate method I have this two lines:
        rp = new RequestPoints(this, url, "admin", "admin");
        rp.execute(""); 
That call another class that make the database conection and have the result of the request.

On the RequestPoints class I have the onPostExecute method that do the following steps:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResponse) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(jsonResponse);

    ArrayList<String> valuesID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> valuesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Procesamos los resultados
    try
    {
        if(jsonResponse!=null)
        {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode =jsonResponse.optJSONArray("tiposPto");

            int lengthJsonArr =jsonMainNode.length();
            for(int i=0; i<lengthJsonArr; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                valuesID.add(jsonChildNode.optString("IdTipoPto")); 
                valuesNames.add(jsonChildNode.optString("Nombre")); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

    }
    String resultID[] = valuesID.toArray(new String[valuesID.size()]);
    String resultPoints[] = valuesNames.toArray(new String[valuesNames.size()]);

    broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("puntos", resultID);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("nombrePuntos", resultPoints);
    broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_REQUEST_POINTS);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    _ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

All the values are added correctly, but when I recieve them on the Broadcast I recieve a null, but the "resultID" and "resultPoints" Arrays have values, I don´t understand why this happend.

```
public class ReceptorBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
        {
            if(RequestPoints.ACTION_REQUEST_POINTS.equals(intent.getAction()))
            {
                pointId = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("puntos");
                pointNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("nombrePuntos");
            }
        }
}
```

In the last pointId and pointNames I recieve a null value, for both. Can someone help me with this problem?

PD: I declare the two variables like this:

```
Point points[];
Paths paths[];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the values use `putStringArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra`

```
broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("puntos", resultID);
broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("nombrePuntos", resultPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `getExtra` use `getSerializableExtra("VALUE")` in your broadcast receiver

Comment: I use "getStringArrayListExtra" , sorry, I change the question now.

Comment: no need to do that..just change the call in your broadcast receiver to the one I told you about in the above post.

Answer (score 0):

Change `intent.getStringArrayListExtra("puntos");` with `intent.getStringArrayExtra("puntos");` .

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29) , `getStringArrayListExtra` returns `ArrayList<String>`, but it seems you are expecting a `String[]`.